# No Man's Sky multiplayer with Steam and GOG users

Tags: steam, no-mans-sky, gog

Finally No Man's Sky has a multiplayer mode.

I have the [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/275850/No_Mans_Sky/) version. So when I want to invite people to my game I see a list of my Steam friends that own this game. But is it also possible for an owner of the [GOG](https://www.gog.com/game/no_mans_sky) version of No Man's Sky to join my game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [2.52 Crossplay Patch](https://www.nomanssky.com/2020/06/crossplay-patch-2-52/) a few months before the big [3.0 "Origins" update](https://www.nomanssky.com/origins-update/) in 2020 added "cross-play" communication between platforms. Now all the various PC users can see each other, as well as see console players.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can answer this question myself:

Looks like [the GOG's version if No Man's Sky doesn't even have the multiplayer feature](https://www.gog.com/news/no_mans_sky_next_update_now_live) so far. So the answer is "No, it's not possible right now".

**Edit: This anser seems to be not valid anymore**

Comment: The NEXT update added multiplayer support.